# Disable scrolling possibility of TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Does anyone know, how to disable scrolling possibility of `TWebBrowser` control in a Firemonkey iOS / Android application? My goal is to get absolutely static element that will not react on touches and so on.

Comment: Have you tried [`Enabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Enabled)? Sounds like what you want.

Comment: WebBrowser don't have Enabled in his properties

Comment: It is the `FMX.Webbrowser.TWebbrowser`, right? Documentation lists that property in [TWebBrowser_Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser_Properties)

Comment: yes it is FMX.Webbrowser but i tried enabled and it don't work

Comment: Have you tried `WebBrowser1.Locked := true;`?

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz `Lock/Locked` only affects design time and is meant to prevent inadvertent moving or resizing. [See here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Locked).

Comment: yes i tried locked and it affects only design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single setting or action that disables all user actions of the `Fmx.TWebBrowser`. But there is a feature you can use for your purpose.

The feature I refer to, is `Fmx.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.CaptureBitmap` [documented here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.CaptureBitmap)

> **Description**
>
> Captures the currently visible Web page as a bitmap.
>
> This method returns a TBitmap object, which allows you to create,
>   manipulate and store images in memory or as files on a disk. The
>   scenario of the use of this method could be as follows: 
>   1. Call this method to capture a visible Web page as a bitmap. 
>   2. Hide a TWebBrowser control. 
>   3. Display the bitmap and overlay other components (such as buttons or popups) on top of the bitmap.

In your case you would just hide the WB and display the bitmap.

Tested with the following code:

```
type
  TForm25 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Image1: TImage;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1DidFinishLoad(ASender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    bmp: TBitmap;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation


procedure TForm25.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.URL := Edit1.Text;
end;

procedure TForm25.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bmp := WebBrowser1.CaptureBitmap;
  Image1.Bitmap := bmp;
end;

procedure TForm25.WebBrowser1DidFinishLoad(ASender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

[image]

With the WB hidden, it cannot be operated on.

The timer (1000 ms) I added because my attempts to capture the image already in the `OnDidFinishLoad()` event did nöt succeed.